# Path to WebContentFile in Spring

Tags: spring, file

I'm using Spring 3 and would like to get the path to a folder I have created under the WebContent folder. I want to create a File instance there.

Answer (score 1):

A real path to the file under webapp root can be obtained using [`ServletContext.getRealPath()`.](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

Note that this method may return `null` if the concept of real path has no sense in your deployment configuration (for example, application is deployed as an unpacked `.war`), in this case you can't create a file there.

An instance of `ServletContext` in Spring can be autowired.

Comment: Is there any other way to create excel file and show it to the user?

Comment: @mjgirl: Using a custom servlet or controller you can serve the generated file from any point of filesystem or serve the file generated on the fly.